# How to get a specific value from a link? Powershell

Tags: powershell

let's imagine I have a link - https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
where I can get the latest Chrome release version. I need to retrieve this value (101.0.4951.41) and write it to the variable. For example, I create variable

$LatestChromeRelease = https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE

so the value of this variable would be '101.0.4951.41'

and I can use it in my further actions.

Please advise how to achieve it in PowerShell script. Thanks!

Comment: You can do: `$LatestChromeRelease = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE' -Method Get` or `$LatestChromeRelease = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE' -Method Get).Content`

Comment: Theo, thank you! that works for me. Could you please help if I can modify another variable like this- 
$client.DownloadFile("https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$LastChromeVersion/chromedriver_win32.zip") 
Where in $LastChromeVersion I need to get the value 101.0.4951.41
Will it work?

Comment: @SergioRamos If you have another problem you need help with, [ask a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - otherwise please [update your existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72228532/edit) with _all the relevant details_ :)

Comment: Lots of people here can help you, but then you need to specify exactly what you need to _modify another variable like this_ ..

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$LatestChromeRelease = (wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE).Content
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the given endpoint returns just the version and nothing else, this is simply a question of sending a web request:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE' -UseBasicParsing
$version = if($response.StatusCode -eq 200){ $response.Content }
```

If the request succeeds, `$version` now holds the string value `"101.0.4951.41"` (or whatever the current latest version number is)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.2)

```
function Get-LatestChromeReleaseVersion{
    $Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
    return $Response.Content    
}

$LatestChromeRelease = Get-LatestChromeReleaseVersion

Write-Host "LatestChromeRelease:"  $LatestChromeRelease
```